# How to get the value of a Django Model Field object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I got a model field object using `field_object = MyModel._meta.get_field(field_name)`. How can I get the value (content) of the field object?

Comment: What you mean by **`value`** of the field ?

Comment: I am sorry, I think I didn't make the right question. I meant that I got the field of a **model instance** and I want the current content of the instance field.

Comment: This way you will get the unbound Field. To receive a value you need to get the Field bound to an instance. Which is usually done by: `MyModel.objects.get(some_query).field_name` or similar.

Comment: If you have a model instance, you don't need these complications. it's simply mode_instance.field_name  - what you get here is the value of that field for the instance that you are holding

Comment: You could get the value by simply, **`MyModel.objects.get(id=id).field_name`** , you don't want to go through all these complications

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge - no, if you do no know `field_name` (e.g. you are receiving it from db or client or somewhere else). Instead you should use `getattr(MyModel.objects.get(id=id), field_name)`

Comment: Anyway, without clarifications from OP it is hard to say what is `field_name` here - is it known or not

Comment: @soon you are right, I receive `field_name` as a string parameter in a function. I have tried your recommendation but I get an object `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10e534748>` and what I am looking for is an actual value, like 'Mexico' (I am testing with field **name** of model **country**)

Comment: Hi everybody. I just wanted to let you know that @soon was right, it works. I was misunderstanding it: I thought the model object was already populated with data from the database, but it wasn't. As soon as I populated it (following your directions), everything worked.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use [`value_from_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.value_from_object):

```
field_name = 'name'
obj = MyModel.objects.first()
field_object = MyModel._meta.get_field(field_name)
field_value = field_object.value_from_object(obj)
```

Which is the same as `getattr`:

```
field_name = 'name'
obj = MyModel.objects.first()
field_object = MyModel._meta.get_field(field_name)
field_value = getattr(obj, field_object.attname)
```

Or if you know the field name and just want to get value using field name, you do not need to retrieve field object firstly:

```
field_name = 'name'
obj = MyModel.objects.first()
field_value = getattr(obj, field_name)
```

Comment: What is `obj` here?

Comment: `obj` is a model instance

Comment: `MyModel.objects.get(id=id).field` will do the exact thing

Comment: No - if you do not know the field name. You should use `getattr(MyModel.objects.get(id=id), field)` instead (assuming `field` is `str`). The OP asks how to retrieve value using field object. This *might* be overkill here, but only OP knows the actual task. This answer shows how to get field value from the model instance by field object - just like the OP wants

Comment: I want to thank you all for taking the time to answer my question. I have tried all your recommendations and I always get an object `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10e534748>`, and what I am looking for is an actual value, like 'Mexico' (I am testing using the field **name** of model **country**).

Comment: Are you sure you are passing model instance, not the model class? Compare `getattr(User, 'username')` and `getattr(User.objects.first(), 'username')`

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you have a model as,

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Then you will get the value of `name` field of model instance by,

```
sample_instance = SampleModel.objects.get(id=1)
value_of_name = sample_instance.name
```

Comment: This will raise an AttributeError if id=1 does not exist....

Comment: repace `1` with a valid PK value

Comment: Thanks @JPG. What if you don't know whether or not the PK value you are using is valid or not...

Comment: @theQuestionMan you can use something like [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it somewhere outside the model You can get it after making an object the Model. Using like this

**OUSIDE THE MODEL CLAA**:

```
myModal = MyModel.objects.all()

print(myModel.field_object)
```

**USING INSIDE MODEL CLASS**
If you're using it inside class you can simply get it like this

```
print(self.field_object)
```

Comment: I don't think using `self` inside Model class would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to return the nth field of a model where all you know is the Model's name. In the below solution the [1] field is the field after pk/id.

```
model_obj = Model.objects.get(pk=pk)
field_name = model_obj._meta.fields[1].name
object_field_value = getattr(model_obj, field_name)
```