# how do i run this filter in Django?

Tags: python, django

i want to write a filter that gets the days with highest order or purchase and get the result as  Monday , Tuesday, Saturday etc.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Show us what did you try by yourself as it's not a free writing code platform, but a platform to help to solve a problem you are facing when something is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the comments, your question is quite vague, but I'll try my best to answer it.

What you might be looking for is the `order_by` function in Django's [Queryset API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), which is just a fancy word for sort. My approach will be to sort the queryset and get the first object of the queryset as you **can** treat certain aspects of a queryset as a python list.

Something like:

```py
# the negative sign means descending (highest to lowest)
highest_order = Order.objects.order_by('-order_count')
```

This will return an *object*. If you only want the string, do something like

```py
# note that highest_order is an Order object
field_object = MyModel._meta.get_field('name')
field_value = getattr(highest_order, field_object.attname)
```

More information on getting field values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905746/12467282).